# Authentication method 'dialog' not supported by any available plugins

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to connect from Windows 7 clients to remote MySQL / MariaDB database servers using Windows/AD authentication using a scripting library - Powershell, Python 2.7 or even MySQL client. On my test Win7 machine, I can successfully use the HeidiSQL client to connect to these databases.

I have installed the drivers for MySQL/Python 2.7, and MySQL - and I have checked to ensure I installed the correct bit version to match the bit version of the client.

I have searched the internet as best I can for this, and my understanding is that MySQL don't supply a dialog.dll which seems to relate to the error message, whereas HeidiSQL have their own dialog.dll.

The full error message is:
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): Authentication method 'dialog' not supported by any available plugins

Comment: Maybe a re-read of [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: you need dialog.dll in a directory where client expect it. Where exactly "MySQL" client expects it, or Python connector with C extension expects dialog.dll to be, is hard to tell. I'd start procmon and see the dll client or python.exe are trying to load. they are using some full path by default